# Grocery Crud: How to identify ID based on URL for custom view?

Tags: php, grocery-crud

I needed to create a custom view in grocery crud, so I have an `add_action` that brings the user to a file called `pastMenuPrint.php`.

I am having trouble coding something that will take the url and determine what `id` it should look up.

Example. `.../scripts/pastMenuPrint.php/2` should look up the past menu for the `id` of `2`.

Is there any way to do that? I am very new to coding and grocery crud, so please keep it simple if you can!

Comment: This is not a proper question for SO buddy. There are multiple forums/sites which can provide you with PHP tutorials using grocery-crud. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you hover action button on some row in crud table the url where that actions leads should appear in the bottom left of your browser and looks something like `/foo/bar/345` 
345 is id of that row in your table, so function that does your magic in pastMenuPrint.php must receive $id

That will look something like this

```
function printMenu($id){
```

That should do the trick, I hope that helps, good luck!